# How do I select this element using xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm having a problem selecting a "delete" button that has to be linked to a certain element.[image]

So I have to click the "x" icon, but it has to be related to the text "teste"...

Here's the HTML code:

[image]

The button I have to click is the span whose class is "fa fa-times" and it has to be related to the div containing the text "teste" because there are other spans with the same class but they are hidden.

Thanks!

Comment: its better to get answers if you share link where you tried this so that others can try, no buddy willing to type code from your shared images, if not possible to share link share html snip at least, also follow MCVE

Answer (score 2):

Use below XPath to select required element:

```
//div[div[text()="teste"]]/following-sibling::div//span[@class="fa fa-times"]
```